# Isn't it incorrect grammar to use "they" in reference to "this user"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, grammatical-correction

When viewing someone's profile who hasn't added bio yet, one gets the following message:

"Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."

Shouldn't *his/her* be used instead of *them*, because, certainly, *them* doesn't refer to "this user".

Comment: It's perfectly valid. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they or anything else that comes up when googling *"singular them"*.

Comment: Nope - it's fine:)

Comment: *"Apparently, this hooman prefers to keep an air of mystery about them."*... there...that's all fixed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, technically. Or perhaps more accurately: yes, according to the classic rules of English grammar.

However, "they" is commonly used in modern English as a workaround for the language's lack of a true gender-neutral singular pronoun. Proposed alternatives like "e" (Spivak pronouns) have never really caught on, "it" is dehumanizing when used to refer to people, and rewriting a sentence to use "one" almost always makes it significantly more cumbersome.

The singular "they" has become so popular that it is generally accepted by most modern style guides.

"His/her" isn't strictly accurate, either, since gender is not a binary (not to mention [studies show](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF00289252) that such constructions are still perceived as discriminatory). Gender equality is a big deal to the folks at Stack Exchange, so this was definitely done intentionally and isn't going to be changed.

Related reading: [Third-person pronouns in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#English) (Wikipedia)

Comment: SE could simply remove the "***about them***" and keep it simple: "***Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery***".